# Can't get pip to not use proxy on linux

Tags: python-3.x, proxy

When I run the command `python3.9 -m pip install pytest-timeout` on linux, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb5e4bb8490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))': /simple/pytest-timeout/
```

I don't have the proxy set (I have disabled it because I'm not at home). Even with

```
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset HTTP_PROXY
```

and

```
export HTTP_PROXY=""
export HTTPS_PROXY=""
```

It doesn't seem to work. I have the proxy disabled every which way I could think of.